# How to soft link/ Hard link a folder to a remote server's folder

Tags: linux, centos, symbolic-link

I'm new to modifying links as well as administering Linux, Is it possible to soft link a specific folder to a remote server's folder?

(I'm not sure what to use hardlinks/symlinks/etc.)

Sorry for being a newb.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have to use soft links (aka [symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink)) as follows:

```
ln -s /net/server/some/dir /home/me/mysymlink
```

If your current working directory is currently `/home/me`, then you can type this instead:

```
ln -s /net/server/some/dir mysymlink
```

Comment: So Basically, I am on a say DIR, I should send a command that goes: <pre> ln -s /homeserver/home/DIR /remote/home/RDIR <code> it the "DIR" that I want to symlink to /remote/home/RDIR. Is that code correct?

Comment: Not sure how to parse your question, but the symlink is always the 2nd parameter to `ln -s ...`.  The 1st parameter is the file or directory that already exists.

Comment: this is not going to work. he wants to link a local file or directory into a remote directory for other clients accessing the remote directory to inspect. that is, the reverse of the solution you described.

Comment: @spyroboy I can see how his question could mean that.  Too bad he asked it so poorly.

Comment: @Fran now that you mention it, it is very vague ...

Answer (score 0):

what filesystems are involved in this configuration? are you using NFS? are you using CIFS/Samba?

you cannot accomplish this from the local filesystem.

given *clientA* and *clientB* are accessing *remoteA* you cannot simply run `user@clientA # ln -s /local/file /remote/directory` as *remoteA* and *clientB* would read `/remote/directory/file` in local scope. that is, when *clientB* is accessing `/remote/directory/file` *clientB* would be accessing `/local/file` on *clientB's* hard drive and not on *clientA's* hard drive.

the way you solve this is to copy the files to *remoteA* or create a network mount from *clientA* to *remoteA* but this needs to be done on *remoteA*.

this is very vague but without a specification of your configuration, I cannot really help further.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the remote filesystem locally (or the local system remotely), which is similar to want, but this depends on the filesystems on each end. If you're doing it from linux to linux, you can most likely use `sshfs`.